# Problems writing more than two "struct" to a file, then read the file

Tags: c, file, fwrite, fread

Im having some trouble with writing more than one struct to the file and then close the program. The next time I open the file and print whats in there, it displays strange text.

If I only choose to print 1 struct plus the obligatory first on that says how many structs are in the file (the first in the file) it displays correct.But as soon as there is more than two https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApXhu.jpg.

I have been looking for a couple hours for the solution but cant find it, would appreciate all the help I can get! :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include "allafunktioner.h"

struct vinnare{
    int ar;
    char namn[20];
};
struct vinnare *inlasningTillFil(struct vinnare *vinnare, int antalvinnareinlasning);
int meny();

int vinnarear(int ar, char namnlista, int vinnare);
void artistnamn(int ar, char namnlista, int vinnare);
void skrivutalla(int ar, int  namnlista, int vinnare);

main(){
    int a=1, val, antalvinnareinlasning,test=0;

    struct vinnare *vinnare;

    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("F:\\Uppgifter", "rb");

    if (file == NULL){

        vinnare = NULL;
        printf("Ange antal vinnare:");
        scanf("%d", &antalvinnareinlasning);
        vinnare = (struct vinnare *)malloc(antalvinnareinlasning*sizeof(struct vinnare));
        vinnare = inlasningTillFil(vinnare, antalvinnareinlasning);
    }
    else{

        fread(&antalvinnareinlasning, sizeof(int), 1, file);
        printf("%d", antalvinnareinlasning);
        vinnare =(struct vinnare *)malloc(antalvinnareinlasning*sizeof(struct vinnare));

        for (a = 1; a < (antalvinnareinlasning + 1); a++){
            fread(&vinnare[a].ar, sizeof(int), 1, file);
            fread(&vinnare[a].namn, sizeof(char)*20, 1, file);
            printf("%d", vinnare[a].ar);
            printf("%s", vinnare[a].namn);
        }


    }
    fflush(stdin);
    getchar();
}


struct vinnare *inlasningTillFil(struct vinnare *vinnare, int antalvinnareinlasning){
    int a, temp;

    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("F:\\Uppgifter", "wb");

    vinnare[0].ar = antalvinnareinlasning;


    fwrite(&vinnare[0], sizeof(struct vinnare),1, file);


    for (a = 1; a < (antalvinnareinlasning + 1); a++){
        printf("Ange vilket år du vill mata in: ");
        scanf("%d", &temp);
        vinnare[a].ar = temp;
        fflush(stdin);

        printf("Ange vinnaren för det året:");
        fgets(vinnare[a].namn, 20, stdin);
        fflush(stdin);

        fwrite(&vinnare[a], sizeof(struct vinnare), 1, file);
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you considered using a debugger?

Comment: Have you considered serialising the data correctly (e.g. to avoid problems when you attempt to read the file on a different computer, caused by differences in implementation dependent things, like padding, endianess, etc)? Only ever read or write bytes.

Comment: Also; never ignore the return value from things like `fread()` or `fwrite()`, and never `fflush(stdin)`.

Answer (score 1):

For the first block of `struct` data, you wrote:

`fwrite(&vinnare[0], sizeof(struct vinnare),1, file);`

i.e. `sizeof(struct vinnare)` bytes of data

but you are reading only `int`

`fread(&antalvinnareinlasning, sizeof(int), 1, file);`

i.e. 4 bytes of data

therefore the `file` pointer is advanced only by 4 bytes and points to 20 bytes of garbage data, which is then followed by next blocks of data that you wrote using `for` in function `inlasningTillFil`.

Comment: Interesting, will look at it when iI get home! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
vinnare = inlasningTillFil(vinnare, antalvinnareinlasning);
```

You are assigning the value of a function that doesn't returns anything

Comment: +1 for pointing that. However, that may not be the real cause for OP's problem, since that is executed only in case `file == NULL`

Answer (score 0):

I seriously doubt this for loop. You are starting from `1`, means **second item** and ending with `number_of_allocations + 1`, clearly out of your allocations.

```
for (a = 1; a < (antalvinnareinlasning + 1); a++){
```